# How to conditionally extract data with the if controller after sampling?

Tags: jmeter

I am extracting the HTML response code from a samplier.  I would like to use the if controller to conditionally extract more information if the right response code is returned.

[image]

So teh Get Message Response Extractor would save the response code to the variable:  GetMessageResponse.

Then the If Controller would check if GetMessageResponse is 200:
[image]

If this is true then extract more information like this:

[image]

However I am not getting anything in ResponseText, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: The answer I accepted WORKS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in one shot if you switch to the [JSR223 PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor), the relevant Groovy code would be:

```
import com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath

if (prev.getResponseCode() == '200') {
    def responseText = JsonPath.read(prev.getResponseDataAsString(),'$.MessageObj.Text').get(0)
    vars.put('ResponseText', responseText)
}
else {
    vars.put('ResponseText','Response code is: ' + prev.getResponseCode())
}
```

References:

- [Jayway JsonPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath)
- [Groovy: Parsing and producing JSON](http://groovy-lang.org/json.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Answer (score 0):

In JMeter what you do is extract whatever the response and set Default Value field to something that will be filled when response will not contain extraction, for example for [JSON Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor):

[image: Default Value]

What you show will not work because you put Extractors in IfController, as there is no Sampler, nothing will happen due to [scoping rules](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#scoping_rules).

Also when you'll need for another thing to use If Controller, no need to extract response code, just use:

> ${JMeterThread.last_sample_ok}